# How many valid utf8 characters are there?

Tags: utf-8

I know that this is a little vague, so for context, think of it as "a character you could tweet," or something like that. My question is how many valid unicode characters are there that a browser or a service that supports utf8 could resolve, in such a way that a utf8 browser could copy and paste it around without any issues.

I guess what I don't want is the full character space, because I know a lot of it is reserved for command characters or reserved characters that wouldn't be shown (unless I'm super wrong!).

Comment: If a character is listed in the Unicode specs, then it has a valid UTF-8 representation. If a unicode codepoint follows the specs, then it's valid. So, yeah, circular logic. It's valid because it's not invalid.

Comment: There’s no way to know whether the display device supports a font that has the specified code points, or even that it does the right thing with them.  You wouldn’t believe how many fonts screw up big time with combining characters, and not always in the same way.

Answer (score 5):

UTF-8 isn't the important factor, since all of the standard Unicode encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32) encode the same character space, just in different ways.

From your explanation I see you don't just want the 1,112,064 valid Unicode code points?

Unicode 6.0 and ISO/IEC 10646:2010 define 109,449 characters, but a handful of those are what you're calling "control characters". Which ones do or don't fall into that category depends on how you're counting. Copying and pasting may result in some characters being treated as identical to one another, or ignore altogether, depending on the OS and the programs doing the copying and pasting.

However because Unicode is forward compatible, some systems will correctly preserve characters which haven't yet been assigned. After all, just because you're running Windows XP and you copy and paste a document with characters that weren't standardised until 2009 doesn't mean you expect them to vanish. There could be a million or so extra possible characters by this way of thinking, although their visual appearance may be indistinguishable in some places.